# Aerokube Selenoid on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, selenoid

Has anyone been able to configure selenoid on aws ecs ? I am able to run the selenoid-ui container but the selenoid hub image keeps throwing an error regarding the browsers.json however I have not been able to find a way to add the browsers.json file because it stops before it executes the CMD command

Comment: Take a look at `docker logs selenoid` to see the actual reason. I think the issue is either in wrong JSON file or in incorrect mount path specification.

Answer (score -1):

There is no point to run selenoid on AWS ECS, as your setup won't scale (your browser containers will be launched on the same EC2 instance where your selenoid container is running). With ECS, you run your service on a cluster, so either your cluster contains on 1 EC2 instance, or you waste your compute resources. 
If you don't need scaling, I'd suggest you run selenoid on simple EC2 instance with docker installed. If you do want to have scaling, then I suggest you to take a look at a commercial version of selenoid (called Moon), which you can run on AWS EKS.

Comment: Thanks for your response Vitaliy, I believe there are 2 options for deploying in AWS ECS which are:
1) On EC2 
2) Using AWS Fargate

I want to take advantage of the auto scaling capabilities of AWS fargate and would like to deploy the selenoid solution on AWS ECS. So far I have only gotten selenoid-ui docker to work under ECS.